# How to check similarity between two name pairs interchangeably and give them a unique identifier in python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows,

```
df_names = pd.DataFrame({'last_name':['Williams','Henry','XYX','Smith','David','Freeman','Walter','Test_A'],
                        'first_name':['Henry','Williams','ABC','David','Smith','Walter','Freeman','Test_B']})
```

A new column full name adding last and first names as below -

[image]

Here i would like to check how similar the full names are ? Williams Henry and Henry Williams to be considered as same and give it a unique identifier some random code.

similarly Smith David and David Smith should also be consider as one unique identifier.

Final expected output as below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
res = (df_names.assign(group=df_names[["last_name", "first_name"]].apply(frozenset, axis=1))
               .groupby("group")
               .ngroup() + 1)

df_names["unique_identifier"] = "A-" + res.astype("string")
print(df_names)
```

**Output**

```
  last_name first_name unique_identifier
0  Williams      Henry               A-1
1     Henry   Williams               A-1
2       XYX        ABC               A-2
3     Smith      David               A-3
4     David      Smith               A-3
5   Freeman     Walter               A-4
6    Walter    Freeman               A-4
7    Test_A     Test_B               A-5
```

The idea is to use [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) to map each row to an object where the order of the elements is irrelevant. It has to be a frozenset so is [`hashable`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable), this is a requirement of pandas.

Comment: Hi @Dani I have a duplicate name as this dictionary: ``` df_names = pd.DataFrame({'last_name':['Williams','Henry','XYX','Smith','David','Freeman','Walter','Test_A','Mallesham','Mallesham'],
'first_name': ['Henry','Williams','ABC','David','Smith','Walter','Freeman','Test_B','Yamulla','Yamulla']}) ```  How to avoid assigning a unique identifier for this entry Mallesham Yamulla

Comment: I just added a screenshot which shows the duplicate entry of mallesham yamulla - it should not be given a unique identifier. where ever the interchange names are appeared those should only be assigned

Comment: But in the screenshot they have the same id, no? name_interchange-16

Comment: Yes just to indicate it to yours i gave it manually. but I don't require a unique identifier for same name in fullname: [Mallesham Yamulla, Mallesham Yamulla] . [Joe Doe, Joe Doe] [Bhavik Kuruma,Bhavik Kuruma] etc etc.. Where ever [Mallesham Yamulla, Yamulla Mallesham] [Yegurla Mahesh, Mahesh Yegurla] is appeared they should be considered as a unique one.

Comment: What should be the output then? for two rows [Joe Doe, Joe Doe]

Comment: What happens if you Doe Joe, Joe Doe, Doe Joe, Joe Doe?

Comment: Where ever we have Joe Doe Joe Doe we will treat these entries separately. Our requirement is to figure out which names are interchanged ? like [Joe Doe, Doe Joe] hope it is clear to yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246676/discussion-between-myamulla-ciencia-and-dani-mesejo).

Comment: Please let me know if any confusion. I'm also looking for other ways

Comment: Hi @dani any update on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = df_names.groupby(lambda idx: tuple(sorted(df_names.iloc[idx])))
```

Output:

```
a.apply(print)

  last_name first_name
2       XYX        ABC
  last_name first_name
5   Freeman     Walter
6    Walter    Freeman
  last_name first_name
0  Williams      Henry
1     Henry   Williams
  last_name first_name
3     Smith      David
4     David      Smith
  last_name first_name
7    Test_A     Test_B
```