# How to apply frozenset on polars dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, rust, python-polars

I have a pandas dataframe as:

```
df_names = pd.DataFrame({'last_name':['Williams','Henry','XYX','Smith','David','Freeman','Walter','Test_A'],
                        'first_name':['Henry','Williams','ABC','David','Smith','Walter','Freeman','Test_B']})
```

[image]

Here i have applied a frozen set on `last_name` and `first_name` columns to see if the names are interchanged i.e williams henry, henry williams.

```
df_names[['last_name','first_name']].apply(frozenset,axis=1)
```

[image]

Here the same kind of implementation is required on polars dataframe. How to get it done ?

[image]

Comment: Could you tell me what you are trying to achieve on a higher level? Turning a column into python frozenset objects is almost always a bad idea and will be terribly slow.

Comment: I would like to find a set of names which are interchanged i.e Joe Doe, Doe Joe

Comment: @ritchie46 if you have any other idea on it please share it here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73079297/how-to-check-similarity-between-two-name-pairs-interchangeably-and-give-them-a-u

Comment: Here i had asked about this requirement on SO earlier. it can be implemented in pandas. i wanted to have it in polars as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @ritchie46 mentioned, you'll want to avoid embedding Python objects (like frozensets) into a Polars DataFrame.  The performance is not good, and columns of type `object` have limited functionality.

Here's a Polars algorithm that will be very performant and will accomplish what you need.

```py
(
    df_names
    .with_column(
        pl.concat_list([
            pl.col("first_name").str.replace_all(r'\s','').str.to_uppercase(),
            pl.col("last_name").str.replace_all(r'\s','').str.to_uppercase(),
        ])
        .arr.sort()
        .arr.join('|')
        .alias('name_key')
    )
    .filter(pl.count().over('name_key') > 1)
)
```

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌───────────┬────────────┬────────────────┐
│ last_name ┆ first_name ┆ name_key       │
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---            │
│ str       ┆ str        ┆ str            │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪════════════════╡
│ Williams  ┆ Henry      ┆ HENRY|WILLIAMS │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Henry     ┆ Williams   ┆ HENRY|WILLIAMS │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Smith     ┆ David      ┆ DAVID|SMITH    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ David     ┆ Smith      ┆ DAVID|SMITH    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Freeman   ┆ Walter     ┆ FREEMAN|WALTER │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Walter    ┆ Freeman    ┆ FREEMAN|WALTER │
└───────────┴────────────┴────────────────┘
```

To help with matching, I've converted names to all uppercase and eliminated white space.  (You can drop that if you don't find it useful.)

Answer (score 0):

`dfl_names.apply` ([docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.apply.html)) will do. You'll need to wrap `frozenset` in `tuple`.