# convert pandas apply to polars apply

Tags: python, python-polars

I am new to python polars and trying to convert the following pandas code to polars.

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[“obj”].compute(data), axis=1, expand = True)
```

Column **obj** in the dataframe **df** is composed of objects having a function property named **compute**. **data** is an external variable in the above code.

When I try the above code using polars,

```
dl.apply(lambda x: (x[0].compute(data)))
```

**dl** is the polars dataframe where the objects are stored in the first column, i.e **0**.

I received the following error message:

‘Expr’ object doesn’t have compute property.

I am also not sure if polars have the expand feature.

Can you please help me how I can convert the above pandas apply to polars apply?

Thank you.

Comment: In general, you want to avoid embedding Python objects into a Polars DataFrame. The performance is not good, and columns of type object have limited functionality.  Perhaps you explain what you are are trying to achieve at a higher level.

Comment: As an example, in this SO question, we were able to find a solution that does not involve embedding objects into a Polars DataFrame:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73398176/how-to-apply-frozenset-on-polars-dataframe

Comment: @cbilot I want to calculate the means of the results obtained using the list of objects. assume that data_in is an array. I want to accomplish the following 

import numpy as np
data_out = [x.compute(data_in) for x in objects]
np.mean(data_out, axis=0)

that is why I converted the objects to pandas and then calculated the means.

Comment: To achieve the massive parallel performance and optimizations that Polars offers, you need to express your objectives "the Polars way": that is, using the Polars Expressions API.  The Polars User Guide may help explain: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/.  (By contrast, embedding objects into Polars DataFrames and using Python byte code is inconsistent with this, and will not yield much benefit for you.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried :

```
df.with_columns([pl.col('obj').apply(lambda d:d.compute(data))])
```

I don´t think its optimal but I think it can work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).